# Any Javascript Database that works in Android, IOS and Windows Phone 8(IE 10)?

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, ios, windows-phone-8

I have an app in Andoid, Iphone and Windows which have ASP.NET Server with SQL Server Database. Now, I want to my app to support offline. For this I need to use the databse on client. I have search but not found an accurate answer. Some people says that IndexDb not work on IOS and some says Web SQl is not maintained? Is there any database that work fine with javascript on  Android, IOS and Windows Phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I can use [IndexedDB](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/indexeddb/todo/) with this [polyfill](https://github.com/facebook/IndexedDB-polyfill).

**Edit:** This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734371/developing-a-html5-offline-storage-solution-for-ios-android-in-2011) shows that [JayData](http://jaydata.org/) is the way to go.